# noindex nofollow for a url that contains some words

Tags: .htaccess, nofollow, noindex

I have a site that contains many urls that are being indexed by Google for example:
https://www.cedarscottages.com/book/online/select/March-1659
https://www.cedarscottages.com/book/online/select/March-1635
But they have the same content and Google detects that, so I would like to prevent all urls that contains book/online/select not be indexed for Google.
I tried to put this on the .htaccess file:


Header set X-Robots-Tag: "noindex, nofollow"


But is not working. thanks

Comment: So just because Google sees identical content, why would you want Google not to see it at all? Better to do a 301, or just remove the duplicates...

Comment: Because users can see, only for SEO is that I don't want to be visible for Google.